# How to find HTTP POST Data sent to a CGI Page?

Tags: http, post, cgi

I searched google for a good number of hours. Maybe I searched for the wrong keywords.
Here is what I want to do.

I'm posting data to a website which then makes a HTTP POST request and returns a .CGI webpage. I want to know the parameters the web page uses to send that HTTP POST request so that I can directly link a page from my Webpage to the final .CGI webpage by making the user enter the data on my own webpage.

How do I achieve it?

Comment: What language are you writing the .cgi script in?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the POST body is piped into STDIN, just read it as a normal file

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm a newbie. I have no idea how to read it. Also I would like to mention the main problem. I'm not posting the request to my own website, I'm posting it to another website. Now how do I read it?